# onClickListener not working for card view

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-cardview

Here it's is my activity_main file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#eeeeee"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView


                android:id="@+id/cardTop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="205dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" >

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lab"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="145dp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/cse1" />

                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardRight"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardTop">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="6"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:src="@drawable/illustration"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>




                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="172dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardleft1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardleft2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardTop" >


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="84dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/support"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:background="#c0c0c0"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardleft2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardleft1"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" >


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="84dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ground"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>


                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/framelLayoutOne"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >
            </FrameLayout>
            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
                app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:itemTextColor="@color/darkgrey"
                app:itemIconTint="@color/darkgrey"
                app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
                android:layout_gravity="start">
            </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout> </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference mUserRef;
    private ImageButton mLogout;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    CardView cardTop, cardLeft1, cardLeft2, cardRight;
    Animation upToDown, leftToRight, downToUp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.string.open, R.string.close);
        cardTop = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.cardTop);
        cardLeft1 = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.cardleft1);
        cardLeft2 = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.cardleft2);
        cardRight = (CardView)findViewById(R.id.cardRight);

        cardTop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent labIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LabInfastructure.class);
                startActivity(labIntent);
            }
        });
        cardRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent dashBoardIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Dashboard.class);
                startActivity(dashBoardIntent);
            }
        });
        cardLeft1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent faculty = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Departments.class);
                startActivity(faculty);
            }
        });
        cardLeft2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent games = new Intent(MainActivity.this,GamesActivity.class);
                startActivity(games);
            }
        });

        upToDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.uptodown);
        cardTop.setAnimation(upToDown);
        leftToRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.lefttoright);
        cardLeft1.setAnimation(leftToRight);
        cardLeft2.setAnimation(leftToRight);
        downToUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.downtotop);
        cardRight.setAnimation(downToUp);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null ){
            mUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        }
}
        public void selectItemDrawer (MenuItem menuItem){
            android.support.v4.app.Fragment myFragement = null;
         //   Fragment myFragement = null;
            Class fragementClass;
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){

                case R.id.db :
                   fragementClass = Dashboard.class;
                   break;
                case R.id.gallery :
                   fragementClass = Gallery.class;
                   break;
                case R.id.contactUs :
                   fragementClass = Contactus.class;
                   break;
                case R.id.aboutCollege :
                   fragementClass = AboutCollege.class;
                   break;
                case R.id.appInfo :
                   fragementClass = AppInfo.class;
                   break;
                case R.id.inviteFriends :
                   fragementClass = InviteFriends.class;
                   break;
                case R.id.info :
                    fragementClass = Info.class;
                    break;
                default:
                    fragementClass = Dashboard.class;
            }
            try{

                myFragement = (android.support.v4.app.Fragment) fragementClass.newInstance();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            FragmentManager fragementManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragementManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelLayoutOne,myFragement).commit();
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
            setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        }
        private void setupDrawerContent (NavigationView navigationView){
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                        selectItemDrawer(item);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser == null){

            sendToStart();
        }
    }
    private void sendToStart() {

        Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,StartActivity.class);
        startActivity(startIntent);
        finish();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return  true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.logout:
                logout();
                return true;

            case R.id.notifications :

                NotificationFragment notificationFragment = new NotificationFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container,notificationFragment).commit();
                break;

            case R.id.newpost :
                    Intent post = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewPostActivity.class);
                    startActivity(post);
                break;

            case R.id.home :
                Intent home = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(home);
                break;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private void logout() {

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

        Intent logoutIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
        //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Logout Btn ... ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        startActivity(logoutIntent);

    }
}
```

when I am trying to add onClickListener to card view it is not working.
am also tried with applying `android:clickable="true"` to all the cardview but no use.It doesn't showing any error and its working fine but onclick listener is not working. can anyone tell me if I have made any mistake done. Is it correct way or any other way is there.

Comment: Not sure if you ever figured this out, but the `DrawerLayout` is covering all of your `CardView`s, and intercepting touch events. That's not how to use `DrawerLayout`. The main content goes _inside_ the `DrawerLayout`, as its first child. You don't layer the `DrawerLayout` on top of everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the click listener on the child view of the card like

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardRight"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardTop">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layRight"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:weightSum="6"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:src="@drawable/illustration"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and on your activity define the linearLayout and try to set onClicklistener with

Comment: but I must need ConstraintLayout when I trying to apply for ConstraintLayout it doesn't working

Comment: In your code no need for ConstraintLayout with only one child imageView , you have two options first use linearLayout instead and second "which is better " to remove the ConstraintLayout and set the imageView directly as a child of cardView

Comment: Actually the card layout will be under the linear or any child view so the click listener will not be affected with the user click because actually he clicks on the child view, not on the card